# Linear algebra: characteristic equation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Just a quick question but I am going over some parts of linear algebra before QM and came across two variations of the characteristic equation.

$(1)$ $\det(I\lambda - A) = 0$ 
$(2)$ $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$

I was wondering if the order matters and if so why?

Comment: $\det(A-\lambda I)$ and $\det(\lambda I-A)$ are the same up to multiplication by $(-1)^n$, where $A$ is a matrix of size $n\times n$. So one is equal to $0$ if and only if the other is. I always prefer to think of the characteristic polynomial as $\det(xI-A)$, because it is easier when $x$ comes with a positive sign. But that's a personal preference.

Comment: Some authors use $\det(A-xI)$ so that the constant term is $\det A$, but as Mark said this is all just preference.

Comment: I would say there is a slight reason to prefer $\det(xI - A)$ because it's a *monic* polynomial in $x$, which is always easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the order doesn't matter. Let's show that for the matrix $A$ of size $n\times n$: $\det(\lambda I-A)=0\Longleftrightarrow \det(-I)\det(A-\lambda I)=0 \Longleftrightarrow (-1)^n \det(A-\lambda I)=0\Longleftrightarrow \det (A-\lambda I)=0$
Hence you can see that two characteristic polynomials of forms  $\det(\lambda I-A)=0$ and $\det (A-\lambda I)=0$ are equivalent.